# Collecting data from all tasks executed on monix Scheduler

Tags: scala, scala-cats, monix, cats-effect

I'm using Monix Scheduler to execute some tasks periodically. But I don't know how to not just execute them, but also to collect result from them to some collection...
Lets say I have a scheduled task that returns a random number every time:

```
val task = Task { Math.random() }
implicit val io: SchedulerService = Scheduler.io()
task.map(_ + 2).map(println).executeOn(io).delayExecution(1.seconds).loopForever.runAsyncAndForget
```

Theoretically speaking, I can create ***mutable and concurrent*** list before task execution, and in `task.map` I can put a result in that list... But I've heard that using mutable, shared between threads, collections isn't the best practice at all... Is there any nice way to collect all scheduled Task results? What instrument should I use to achieve this goal in a proper, scala idiomatic way, avoiding mutable collections?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The idiomatic way to collect repeated results using Monix would be to use an [Observable](https://monix.io/api/3.0/monix/reactive/Observable.html) instead of a `Task`. It has many methods such as `zipMap` to combine results with another `Observable`, and many methods such as `foldLeft` to combine results with previous results of the same `Observable`.

Note this generally requires collecting all your `Observables` into one method instead of the fire and forget method in your example. Ideally, you have exactly one `runAsync` in your entire program, in your `main` function.